# Does the property of "reflecting monomorphisms" for a functor, implies its faithfulness?

Tags: category-theory

I can see why

> If $F$ is faithful, then it reflects monomorphisms.

My question is does the inverse holds? More generally, I would like to ask:

> What are the alternative ways of defining the faithfulness of functors (Apart from "*..one which its restriction to home sets is bijective*)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the second question. (That is not the definition of faithfulness.)

Comment: Re: alternate ways of defining faithfulness, check magma's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166281/why-is-full-faithful-functor-defined-in-terms-of-set-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $C$ be a groupoid. Then any functor $F : C \to D$ reflects monomorphisms (because every morphism in $C$ is a monomorphism) but most of them are not faithful.